# Simultaneous equation involving reciprocals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

"Hannah and Tim both think of a number.

Hannah's number is negative. Tim's number is one more than Hannah's. They each take the reciprocal of their numbers. The sum of the reciprocals is $\frac{5}{6}$.

Use algebra to work out Hannah's original number."

I'm struggling with this question. It clearly makes a simultaneous equation but after that I'm unsure of how to solve it.

So far: Let $x$ be Hannah's number and let $y$ be Tim's number. From the question I get the two equations:
$$x+1=y$$
$$\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} = \frac{5}{6}$$
I tried taking the reciprocal of the last equation but I found out that $(x+y)^{-1}$ is not the same as $x^{-1} + y^{-1}$ and as such I can't figure out how to take the reciprocal.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Multiplying the last equation by $xy$ and simplifying might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hannah and Tim both think of a number.

We introduce unknowns $h$ and $t$.

> Hannah's number is negative.

$$
h < 0
$$

> Tim's number is one more than Hannah's.

$$
t = h + 1
$$

> They each take the reciprocal of their numbers. The sum of the
>   reciprocals is $\frac{5}{6}$.

$$
\frac{1}{h} + \frac{1}{t} = \frac{5}{6}
$$

And implicitly it gives
$$
h \ne 0 \\
t \ne 0
$$

> Use algebra to work out Hannah's original number.

$$
\frac{5}{6} = \frac{t + h}{h t} \Rightarrow \\
\frac{5}{6} h t =  h + t 
$$
The equations are not equivalent, because the second equation would also allow for $h = t = 0$.

If we now insert the equation of $t$ in terms of $h$ we get:
$$
\frac{5}{6} h (h+1) = 2 h + 1 \iff \\
h^2 + h = \frac{12}{5} h + \frac{6}{5} \iff \\
h^2 - \frac{7}{5} h - \frac{6}{5} = 0 \iff \\
\left( h - \frac{7}{10} \right)^2 - \frac{7^2}{10^2} - \frac{12}{10} = 0 \iff \\
\left( h - \frac{7}{10} \right)^2 = \frac{169}{100}  \iff \\
h = \frac{7}{10} \pm \sqrt{\frac{169}{100}}
  = \frac{7 \pm 13}{10} \in \{ -0.6, 2 \}
$$
This means $h = -0.6 \in \mathbb{Q}$.